# Can I serialize a single object into nested XML?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I need to create some XML with nested attributes that looks something similar to this:

```
<1>
  <1a>
     Some stuff
  </1a>
  <1b>
     Some stuff
     <1c>
       Some stuff
     </1c>
  </1b>
</1>
```

Usually to create nested elements the object has had nested classes inside it.  However the XML I need to create would result in an object with 20+ nested classes inside, which smells horrible to me.  None of the elements are repeated, so I don't see the need to create all these classes.

Is there a way to tell the XML serializer to nest the elements instead? For example on an attribute in a class like this:

```
public class XMLExport
{
   [DataMember(Order = 0, Name = "1")]
   public string 1 { get; set; }

   [DataMember(Order = 1, Name = "1/1a")]
   public string 1a { get; set; }

   [DataMember(Order = 2, Name = "1/1b")]
   public string 1b { get; set; }

   [DataMember(Order = 3, Name = "1/1b/1c")]
   public string 1c { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you use IXmlSerializable and implement the WriteXml method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx

Comment: Any chance you can use an XDocument instead? It's much easier to work with XDocuments than the XML serializer and you can easily nest XElements.

Comment: @leon I could, I was just hoping to avoid it.  The XML that needs producing is quite complex, and would take a bit of work

Comment: @ZachSmith Sure, there's no restriction on how I do it, I'm merely looking for the best way.  Thanks I'll take a look at it

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer rather than as an update to your question. This is to help future visitors and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XmlElement` attribute will get you one level deep, like this:

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "1"]
public string 1 { get; set; }
```

but that won't meet your needs, so...

Check out [YAXLib: Yet Another XML Serialization Library for the .NET Framework](http://yaxlib.codeplex.com/).

It claims to have `support for specifying path-like serialization addresses, e.g., elem1/elem2/elem3, and ../elem1, and ./elem1`.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately one level deeps not enough, but the YAXLib looks very promising, thanks

Comment: Yes, the YAXLib had exactly what I was looking for! Although I would have liked to write something myself, because its an open source project I was able to integrate the code into our framework for the same result. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Trying using an XDocument instead. XDocuments are wonderful and easy to work with compared to the XML Serializer.The MSDN documentation on it is amazing. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx

Using their example, you could create your example xml file like so:

```
XDocument srcTree = new XDocument(
    new XComment("This is a comment"),
    new XElement("1",
        new XElement("1a", "Some Stuff"),
        new XElement("1b",
            new XElement("1c", "Some Stuff"
        )
    )
);
```

Then to save it just

```
srcTree.save("path\to\file");
```

Comment: This looks very promising, I'll investigate this option further. Thanks

Comment: This is the best option to construct XML documents.

Answer (score 2):

Just because i like doing things with LINQ, here is an alternative:

Lets say you have a Class like this:

```
public class lClass
{
    public string la{get;set;}
    public string lb{get;set;}
    public string lc{get;set;}
}
```

And you have a List of this class:

```
List<lClass> l = new List<lClass>();
l.Add(new lClass{la ="1 Some Stuff a",lb ="1 Some Stuff b",lc = "1 Some Stuff c"});
l.Add(new lClass{la ="2 Some Stuff a",lb ="2 Some Stuff b",lc = "2 Some Stuff c"});
l.Add(new lClass{la ="3 Some Stuff a",lb ="3 Some Stuff b",lc = "3 Some Stuff c"});
l.Add(new lClass{la ="4 Some Stuff a",lb ="4 Some Stuff b",lc = "4 Some Stuff c"});
```

With the following code:

```
XElement xe = new XElement("root");
xe.Add
  (
    l.Select 
    (
        x => 
        new XElement
        (
            "l",
            new XElement
            (
                "la",
                x.la
            ),
            new XElement
            (
                "lb",
                x.lb,
                new XElement
                (
                    "lc",
                    x.lc
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

You get:

```
<root>
  <l>
    <la>1 Some Stuff a</la>
    <lb>1 Some Stuff b<lc>1 Some Stuff c</lc></lb>
  </l>
  <l>
    <la>2 Some Stuff a</la>
    <lb>2 Some Stuff b<lc>2 Some Stuff c</lc></lb>
  </l>
  <l>
    <la>3 Some Stuff a</la>
    <lb>3 Some Stuff b<lc>3 Some Stuff c</lc></lb>
  </l>
  <l>
    <la>4 Some Stuff a</la>
    <lb>4 Some Stuff b<lc>4 Some Stuff c</lc></lb>
  </l>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your options are limited here:

1) Have your class structure reflect the XML structure and use simple framework annotations - this is the nested class member structure you already mentioned a distaste for.

2) Implement IXmlSerializable and do custom serialization. This *is* custom serialization, after all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a class with a self reference, like bellow:

```
    public class Item
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public Item[] ChildList { get; set; }

    }
```

And then you will have the following:

```
    var obj = new Item
    {
        Value = "Something",
        ChildList = new[]
        {
            new Item
            {
                Value = "Something",
                ChildList = new[]
                {
                    new Item
                    {
                        Value = "Something",
                        ChildList = new[] { new Item() {Value = "End"} }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Item));

    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <Value>Something</Value>
      <ChildList>
        <Item>
          <Value>Something</Value>
          <ChildList>
            <Item>
              <Value>Something</Value>
              <ChildList>
                <Item>
                  <Value>End</Value>
                </Item>
              </ChildList>
            </Item>
          </ChildList>
        </Item>
      </ChildList>
    </Item>
```

Comment: Interesting method, but would involve writing complex classes which I'm trying to avoid. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Karls answer I used [YAXLib](http://yaxlib.codeplex.com/) to do this, which gave nice, neat classes like the following:

```
public class XMLExport
{
   [YAXElementFor("")]
   [YAXSerializeAs("1")]
   public string 1 { get; set; }

   [YAXElementFor("1")]
   [YAXSerializeAs("1a")]
   public string 1a { get; set; }

   [YAXElementFor("1")]
   [YAXSerializeAs("1b")]
   public string 1b { get; set; }

   [YAXElementFor("1/1a/1b")]
   [YAXSerializeAs("1c")]
   public string 1c { get; set; }
}
```

`YAXElementFor` allows you to put a path so that you can nest the element.

`YAXSerializeAs` allows you to change the name of the element in case it needs to differ from the property name.

There are a tonne of other options too.